error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:3306 on Strapi with MySQL
I have a problem with connecting my Strapi app locally. I'm receiving that error :
$ strapi develop
[2024-05-13 15:43:43.535] warn: @strapi/plugin-documentation has deprecated registerDoc, use strapi.plugin('documentation').service('override').registerOverride() instead
[2024-05-13 15:43:43.608] info: Using Local Image Sharp plugin
[2024-05-13 15:43:43.609] info: - Source directory: /Users/mac/Dev_jobs/BONUX/backend/public
[2024-05-13 15:43:43.609] info: - Cache directory: /Users/mac/Dev_jobs/BONUX/backend/.image-cache
[2024-05-13 15:43:43.869] debug: ⛔️ Server wasn't able to start properly.
[2024-05-13 15:43:43.870] error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:3306
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:3306
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1555:16)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (/Users/mac/Dev_jobs/BONUX/backend/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (/Users/mac/Dev_jobs/BONUX/backend/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:51:23)
    at Connection.connect (/Users/mac/Dev_jobs/BONUX/backend/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:116:18)
    at /Users/mac/Dev_jobs/BONUX/backend/node_modules/knex/lib/dialects/mysql/index.js:66:18
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Client_MySQL.acquireRawConnection (/Users/mac/Dev_jobs/BONUX/backend/node_modules/knex/lib/dialects/mysql/index.js:61:12)
    at create (/Users/mac/Dev_jobs/BONUX/backend/node_modules/knex/lib/client.js:252:39)
error Command failed with exit code 1.

If I check if the MySQL server is running with the commande : /usr/local/bin/mysql.server status, it says SUCCESS! MySQL running
Here is my database.js file :
module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
  connection: {
    client: "mysql",
    connection: {
      host: env("DATABASE_HOST"),
      port: env.int("DATABASE_PORT"),
      database: env("DATABASE_NAME"),
      user: env("DATABASE_USERNAME"),
      password: env("DATABASE_PASSWORD"),
      ssl: env.bool("DATABASE_SSL", false),
    },
  },
});

I don't really know where else to check to find the solution.

The problem is that this is not really a programming error, this is a configuration error! We cannot tell you how to fix it. We can tell you what the usual causes of this error are (these are already listed in lots of answers to lots of the same question), but you need to figure out which of these apply to you. Please check out Brendan's answer to the duplicate question - that lists all the possible causes.

The solution that worked for me was to change localhost to 127.0.0.1
